# Need to calculate difference of days between joining date and today's date in year,month and days format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Dates

```
Opendate        Closedate       
2016-02-26      NULL    
2017-01-01      NULL    
2015-11-11      NULL
```

I want to have the output as

```
Opendate    Workingperiod       
2016-02-26  1 years 0 months 1 days         
2017-01-01  0 years 1 months 26 days     
2015-11-27  1 years 3 months 0 days
```

We need to calculate the difference between opendate and today's date and in year month and days format.

Is there any inputs any1 can share.

Comment: This is a real pain in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Dates(Opendate DATE, CloseDate DATE)

INSERT INTO Dates(Opendate, CloseDate) values('2016-02-26', null),('2017-01-01',null),('2015-11-11',null)

SELECT Opendate,
       CASE WHEN DAY(Opendate)>DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 
         CAST(DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE())/12 AS VARCHAR(5))+' year '+
         CAST((DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE())%12-1) AS VARCHAR(5)) +' month '+
         CAST(DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE())-1,Opendate),EOMONTH(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())))+DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(5))+' days ' 
         ELSE
           CAST(DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE())/12 AS VARCHAR(5))+' year '+
           CAST(DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE())%12 AS VARCHAR(5)) +' month '+
           CAST(DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,Opendate,GETDATE()),Opendate),GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(5))+' days '
       END AS 'Workingperiod'     
  FROM Dates
```

above it's my script , hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanx @victor it woks like a charm.

Comment: Victor I have 1 problem with the code, when my joining date is 2014-06-02 00:00:00, my output is coming as 2 year 9 month -1 days. My days comes in negative

Comment: oh...Red I hadn't consider another condition that DAY(Opendate) greater than DAY(current date). now we should use a function of EOMONTH() which support from SQL Server 2012. updated my answer.

Comment: Victor but I am using sql2008

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 11
'EOMONTH' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Hey Victor is there any way we can achieve the same thing in sqlserver2008

Comment: Red sorry for the late replay , busy for work . i think  there are many ways to achieve EOMONTH(). for your case, using  "DATEADD(day,-DAY(GETDATE()),getdate()) " to replace "EOMONTH(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE()))"

Comment: Thanx alot Victor, I really appreciate all your efforts.

Comment: Victor as it was happening before for days which was coming as -1 days and like that, now month is also coming as that -2 month. for eg: if my joining date is 2016-03-21 00:00:00 it is coming as 1 year -1 month 11 days which is completely incorrect, can you tell me what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work - a bit of combined date arithmetics (I am adding CURRENT_DATE to show what we are calculating from); the WITH clause is just the input you showed.

```
WITH
input(Opendate,Closedate) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2016-02-26',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-01',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-11-11',NULL
)
SELECT 
  GETDATE( ) AS current_date
, Opendate
, CAST(DATEDIFF(MONTH, Opendate,GETDATE( )) / 12 AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' years '
+ CAST(DATEDIFF(MONTH, Opendate,GETDATE( )) % 12 AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' months '
+ CAST(
    DATEDIFF(
      DAY
    , Opendate
    , DATEADD(
        MONTH
      , DATEDIFF(MONTH, Opendate,GETDATE( )) * -1
      , GETDATE( )
      )
    ) 
  AS VARCHAR(3)
  ) + ' days'
AS WorkingPeriod
FROM input;

current_date|Opendate  |WorkingPeriod
2017-02-26  |2016-02-26|1 years 0 months 0 days
2017-02-26  |2017-01-01|0 years 1 months 25 days
2017-02-26  |2015-11-11|1 years 3 months 15 days
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_DATE'.

Comment: Could not test it against SQL server, and I'm surprised that SQL Server does not even support the ANSI standard CURRENT_DATE pseudocolumn. It's `GETDATE()` instead. I edited my answer.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '|'.

Comment: Ok. Concatenation operator in SQL Server is also strange and not ANSI. It's the `+` sign and not the double bar. Changed the answer.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 11
'MOD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Changed to the `%` modulo operator. Another ANSI thing. Script changed.

Comment: I have 1 problem with the code, when my joining date is 2014-06-02 00:00:00, my output is coming as 2 year 9 month -1 days. My days comes in negative